# Confused with changing lists

Tags: python, list

I'm stuck on this weird thing in Python where changing one thing messes with another. But with other variables it works fine.

How do I fix this?

```
example = [1, 2, 3,4,5]
new = example
new[3] = 6
print(example)
```

Which outputs [1, 2, 3, 6, 5] instead of [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: `new` is an alias for `example` at the moment. If you want to take a standalone copy you should use `new = example[::]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you set new = example, you're essentially making both of them refer to the exact same memory location. Hence any change made to one will be seen in the other.
We can correct this with

```
new = example[:]
```

Although in some cases you need to

```
import copy
new = deepcopy(example)
```